# R Creating binary variables for each factor of a categorical variable - For assessing the importance and information gain from each predictor

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data frame that contains a categorical variable with 6 levels.

```
x$response <- data.frame(rep(1:6,10))
x
```

I would like to create 6 different binary columns based on the level. For Eg:

```
x$response1 <- 0
    x$response1[x[,1]=='1'] <- 1

x$response2 <- 0
    x$response2[x[,1]=='2'] <- 1
```

I can do it the above mentioned way, but need to repeat it 6 times. I would like to know if there is better way to do it. And what can i do, Say if i have 30 levels?

My ultimate goal is to assess the importance or information gain from each predictor. I am doing this to create a logit model for each response category and perform anova using different combinations of predictors.But, how can I assess information gain for each predictor and response category combination.

Comment: FYI, it is unnecessary to create dummy variables for lm in R, in case that's what you're going for.

Comment: @JohnMadden only if you cast `x` to factor in either the `data.frame` or `formula` objects.

Answer (score 5):

```
x <- data.frame(response = factor(rep(1:6,10)))
model.matrix(~., x)
```

For bonus points:

```
Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(~., x)
```

As noted by John Madden in the comments, R does the former automatically inside most modeling functions, e.g. `lm`.  Note also that this is not the full matrix.  R automatically drops the first dummy variable to avoid the [dummy variable trap](http://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html).  You can turn this behavior off as follows (note that in this case the intercept term is dropped):

```
model.matrix( ~ 0 + ., x)
Matrix::sparse.model.matrix( ~ 0 + . , x)
```

For larger datasets, `sparse.model.matrix` is probably your best bet:

```
#100 factor levels
library(microbenchmark)
library(Matrix)
x <- rep(1:100,1000)
microbenchmark(
  mm = model.matrix(~0+factor(x)),
  smm = sparse.model.matrix(~0+factor(x)),
  o = outer(x, unique(x), `==`),
  m = sparseMatrix(1:length(x), match(x,unique(x))),
  times=25
)
```

`sparseMatrix(1:length(x), match(x,unique(x)))` is even faster, if that's what you need.

```
#10 levels
library(microbenchmark)
library(Matrix)
x <- rep(1:10,10000)
microbenchmark(
  mm = model.matrix(~0+factor(x)),
  smm = sparse.model.matrix(~0+factor(x)),
  o = outer(x, unique(x), `==`),
  sm = sparseMatrix(1:length(x), match(x,unique(x))),
  times=25
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient version of Zach's approach

```
outer(x, sort(unique(x)), `==`)
```

Comment: Yields "Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing decreasing)) : undefined columns selected" for me

Comment: @Zach Change your code to `x <- rep(1:6, 10)` instead, or properly reference the data.frame variable with `x$response` instead.

Comment: I think `Matrix::sparse.model.matrix` is more efficient on larger datasets.

Comment: @Zach You have to include creating the factor as part of the benchmark. Not only does it call a sort unique, but it recodes a as a factor variable. Not necessary with my method. Factor sucks in R. Sparse matrix depends moreover on the number of factor variables. For fewer levels (most common data analysis case) the matrix is not that sparse.

Comment: Good point. I updated my timings.It looks like sparse model matrix wins if you have ~100 factor levels, but for 10, your function wins.  I came up with an even more optimized version too.